# How to avoid duplication code in component Angular?

Tags: angular

I have the following component:

```
export class OrdersExecutionListComponent implements OnInit {
    public legend: Legend;

    constructor(
        public paginationService: PaginationService,
        public applicationService: ApplicationService,
        private listService: ListService,
    ) {
        this.legend = legendRepository.legendExecution;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.listService.onChanged.subscribe((sortedList: ListItem[]) => {
            const sortBy = sortedList.map((item) => item.key).join();
            this.getExecutionApplications(this.paginationService.getOffset(), this.paginationService.getLimit(), sortBy);
        });

        this.getExecutionApplications(this.paginationService.getOffset(), this.paginationService.getLimit());
    }

    getExecutionApplications(offset: number, limit: number, sortBy?: string): void {
        this.applicationService.getExecutionApplications(offset, limit, sortBy);
    }
}
```

As you can see the method `this.getExecutionApplications` is called twice in ngInit, one time by default and another when chnages comes in subscribe.

I dislike this notation. How can I improve it?

Comment: it needs to load data on the page by default

Comment: What happends if you don't call default one?

Comment: Then I dont get information on the page,  when I call it I request a service that makes request get to the server

Comment: So, I have a service method, that I can call in two cases. `this.applicationService.getExecutionApplications(offset, limit, sortBy);` where `sortBy` is optional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are calling `getExecutionApplications` outside the subscription as `onChanged` doesn't fire on initialisation, you can use `startWith` to force it to emit, and only pass `sortBy` if relevant:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.listService.onChanged.pipe(startWith(null)).subscribe((sortedList: ListItem[]) => {
        const sortBy = sortedList ? sortedList.map((item) => item.key).join() : undefined;
        this.getExecutionApplications(this.paginationService.getOffset(), this.paginationService.getLimit(), sortBy);
    });
}
```